# Can we use Cocos2d-x V3 with Spritebuilder?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, spritebuilder

Cocos2d-x v3. i wants to design my game screen. is it possible to use or any other tool provide to design screen?

Thanks

Comment: nope, spritebuilder has no (official/maintained) support for cocos2d-x

Comment: are there any other tools available?

Comment: Have you tried to google this at all? There's even a tools list on the cocos2d-x page: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/hub/all?category=4

Comment: You can use CocosBuilder (although a bit dated) and there is also CocosStudio: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Cocos2d-x

Answer (score 3):

You can have a try: http://jacos2d-x.org/jchome/  I have not test it.